# Creating a route template that matches all urls that starts with a specific pattern in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0, asp.net5

I have an application that is written on the top of ASP.NET Core 5 / .NET 5 Framework. I need to create a route template that would direct any URL that starts with `/homes-for-sale-in-{city}-{id:int}` to define controller/action.

Here are some examples of urls

```
/homes-for-sale-in-los-angeles-100/condo,apartment_type
/homes-for-sale-in-los-angeles-100/0-5000_price/10_page
/homes-for-sale-in-los-angeles-100/condo_type/0-5000_price/2_page
.... yes there are many more
```

I tried the following pattern

```
[Route("/homes-for-sale-in-{city}-{id:int}{*.}", Name = "HomesForSaleByCity")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Display(string city, id? id)
{
    return View();
}
```

But I get this error:

> RoutePatternException: A path segment that contains more than one section, such as a literal section or a parameter, cannot contain a catch-all parameter.

How can I add a pattern that would redirect any url that would starts with a pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did the trick

```
[Route("/homes-for-sale-in-{city}-{id:int}/{**filters}", Name = "HomesForSaleByCity")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Display(string city, id? id, string filters = "")
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use regex for your routing, and may refer [this page](https://asp.mvc-tutorial.com/routing/routing-constraints/) once.

Comment: the problem that I am running into here is that the route constrains are applied on the URL parts not on the entire path. meaning the url (for example `/homes-for-sale-los-anegles-100/0-100_price/0-3_beds`) is broken to parts using `/` then the route constraint is applied. I need to find a way to hook into the routing engine to apply some constrains/regex before the request's path is split into parts.